# Problem after cloning a System drive from my laptop

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, clone

I just made a clone of my notebooks Harddrive using Norton Ghost 11 boot-CD.
The system is Windows XP on an IBM Thinkpad r60 (type 9461).
The cloning went ok.
Now with the new HDD in the machine I have an error message saying:
"A disk read error occured
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart".

The Bios isn't giving me a lot of options!
What shall I do?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: The old HDD was 100GB, the new one is 250GB... Could it just not be accepted from the IBM board?

EDIT2: After looking around by Lenovo/IBM, I found out the max capacity of HDD I can buy for that model is 100GB!!! Can it be true that the board doesn't accept more??? What a pity in that case...

Comment: What do you see in the Event Log?

Comment: Event log? I can't even pass the Boot!

Comment: Runing the "Hard disk diag program" from the BIOS... It's just so slow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, some laptops will only accept hard drives up to a certain size.  I've had this problem before several times.

Answer (score 1):

> After looking around by Lenovo/IBM, I
>   found out the max capacity of HDD I
>   can buy for that model is 100GB!!! Can
>   it be true that the board doesn't
>   accept more???

yes, that can be true.

however, check if the partition is active. if not, make it so and try again.